# jQuery, reverse $.each of sorts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to run down a `UL` set:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Header 1</h2>
        <ul class="collapse">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <ul class="collapse">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>
                <h2>Header 3</h2>
                <ul class="collapse">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>
                        <h2>Header 4</h2>
                        <ul class="collapse open">
                            <li>A</li>
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li>C</li>
                            <li>D</li>
                            <li>E</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where if I find one of the children with the class `open` I want to remove the class `collapse` and/or `open` from any parent level UL's prior to that child found with `open`. Maybe I'm to tired, but I have this seriously flawed logic, in my head I am trying to make sense of it, at the same time I feel its not logical, and theres bound to be an easier way to do this. (Mind you the `$.each()` I am currently attempting is flawed and doesnt work anyway). But I could use some ideas how to approach this if anyones go some.

```
$('ul').each(function()
{
    if($(':not(:first)', this))
    {
        if($(this).hasClass('collapse'))
        {
            alert('collapse found');
            $kid = $(this).child('ul');

            if($kid.hasClass('open'))
            {
                alert('uh')
                $kid.parents('ul').removeClass('collapse');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put some sort of an identifier or class on your top `ul`, you can do something like this:

```
$('.collapse .open')
    .parentsUntil('#root', 'ul.collapse')
    .removeClass('collapse');
```

---

Edit: Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/vA5Gu/

Also, even though not stated in the question, it sounds like you might also want to remove the `collapse` class on the element with the `open` class as well?  If so, you just need to add the `addBack()` command.  E.g.,

```
$('.collapse .open')
    .parentsUntil('#root', 'ul.collapse')
    .addBack()
    .removeClass('collapse');
```

Which is demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/vA5Gu/1/

Comment: This actually kind of works (unfortunately I am stuck with jQuery 1.4 and its earliest adoption of `parentsUntil()`). So `addBack()` doesn't work for me, but the first version does nice. Only problem is all parents prior to there classes remove find, however the child that sparks it so to speak remains stuck with the classes that need removing

Comment: actually adding a `removeClass()` then the rest solved that issue, love chaining..

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.open:has(li.open)').removeClass('open collapse');
```

Find all `UL`'s with the `.open` class, and check if they contain a `LI` with the `.open` class, if so remove both `open` and `collapse` classes if present.

Comment: This is a nice idea, unfortunately I think its going against the grain I seek. Initially I was using `$('ul:first-child').find('ul.open').removeClass('collapse open');` as my means of doing what I needed, then I realized there is the occasional case where one of the child elements within a parent element may have a class with `open`. Where if it does, and the parent doesn't I want to remove the open and collapse class from all parents of that initial child element (as well as the child element that was found with open initially)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the issue clearly, but would this work?

```
$('.collapse.open').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul.collapse').removeClass('collapse');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.collapse .open').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('collapse');
});
```

I think this would work. I'd need to test in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.collapse.open').each(function(){
    $(this).parents('ul.collapse, ul.open').removeClass('collapse open');
});
```